# R - What does ggplot2 use as its backend for graphing?

Tags: c++, r, ggplot2, implementation, graphing

I was wondering how the package `ggplot2` renders its graphics or what frameworks/libraries it uses. I think it has some C++ components, so I'm wondering if it uses an R, C++, or even JavaScript library to do its work for  it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ggplot`, and `lattice` too, are based on the `grid` package by Paul Murrell. It is a rewrite of basic graphical capabilities and so does not use the `base` package. The code's on github (see link in the comment below), and you can see that it uses both R and C.

Paul Murrell's book, [R Graphics](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RG2e/) is a great reference for R graphics in general.

Comment: You can easily browse the code [here](https://github.com/cran/grid). Plenty of R in the R directory, plenty of C in the SRC directory.

Comment: Actually, this code looks out of date. `grid` is now part of basic R and this code is version 0.7-4, which was for R version 1.7. But I'd guess the new version uses both R and C too.

Comment: yea that source is ancient, here is the current https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library/grid

Answer (score -2):

The backend is simply the R base graphics package.

Comment: If I may ask, what does the base R graphics package use?

Comment: At a base level, much of R is written in C and FORTAN. I am not 100% sure about this, but I think that the graphics package is written in R itself.

Comment: it's not though. It's the grid package, these are two different graphics systems in R.